# How can I perform multiple actions with one button of a button panel?

Tags: space-engineers

Is it possible to have a button on a button panel which triggers multiple actions when pressed?

For example: Change the velocity of a piston to close a blast door, have a sound block play an alarm and make multiple interior lights blink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a timer block and assign all the actions you want to it.

Then set the button's action to the "trigger now" action of the timer block.